# turn.js: altering URL when using mouse to change page

Tags: jquery, url, turnjs

I'm using `turn.js` on a website I'm working in and have had some issues relating to altering the `URL` when using the mouse flip through the pages of the book like site. 
So far I've tried:

```
flipbook.bind('start', function (event, page, corner) {
    if (corner == 'tr') {
        changeUrl('plus'); //just a function that increments page number
    } else if (corner == 'tl') {
        changeUrl('minus'); //just a function that decrements page number
    }
});
```

This work in that when the page turns, it updates my `URL` using the `changeUrl()` function. However it changes the page already when I hover over the edges of the page. I need the page to turn only after I've `click`ed the page corners and not already when hovering over them.

I've also tried

```
    flipbook.bind('turning', function (event, page, corner) {
        if (page%2 == 0) {
           changeUrl('plus');
        } else if (page%2 != 0) {
           changeUrl('minus');
        }
    });
```

Which works technically, but it messes up my links and sends me to the final page of the `turn.js` app no matter where I've set the link to go to.

If anyone knows any other way manipulate what happens when I use the mouse `click` on `turn.js` and not on `hover` I would really appreciate some help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It should work

```
flipbook.bind('turning',function (event, page, corner) {
    Hash.go('page/'+page).update();
});
```